# Optical phenomena due to temperature gradient in the atmosphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

What kind of phenomena can we observe due to the deviation of the light in the atmosphere, for example when the reflection index vary with the altitude. I would say that the orange lights in the twilight is a consequence of such effects but I'm not sure.
By the way, this is a question I've been ask in a class of optical geometry.

Comment: Desert Mirage is a prime example, but there are *many* others

Comment: The main effect is a small apparent shift in the position of stars, https://britastro.org/node/17066

Comment: Yeah, that's true, celestial bodies are refracted and their positions are not as we can see on Earth. I also found that stars near the observer horizon exhibit more scintillation than those that approach the zenith of the observer